# Using the ratio test when the limit of ratio is infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If the limit in ratio test is infinity. Does the sequence converge? I suspect not as it is infinity and not some finite value but I'm not sure.

Any help?

Comment: See the proof of the Raabe's test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test

Comment: sequence or series?

Comment: Is infinity smaller or larger than one ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does converge. It doesn't matter if it goes to infinity, because it is still positive. The ratio test only requires the limit to be strictly greater 1.

Comment: Surely you mean diverge?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the comparison test for to prove that the series not converge if the limit in the ratio test is $>1$. Compare with the series of geometric progression with ratio $r>1$.